# add a .Net5.0 package to project with .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project which has been built by .netcoreapp3.1. and now I need to add a .net5.0 package to it and as you can guess I get an error.

> Package [package-name] is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package [package-name] supports: net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)

I wonder if there is any solution to solve this, instead of migrating the project to .net5.0?

Comment: If the question is "can I import something intended for a newer framework into my old framework", then the answer is obviously no. You'd be missing the new bits, after all.

Comment: but i doubt what package(from nuget?) only suports `.net 5` and above?

Comment: @LeiYang this is an internal package that has been built by .net5. I can add that manually but I canot add the package from the package feed due to the error I have sent. that is really wierd.

Comment: You have to recompile the 5.0 package with 3.1 to see if it is compatible.